# How to extract the value between the key using RegEx?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, split

I have text like:

```
"abababba"
```

I want to extract the characters as a list between `a`.
For the above text, I am expecting output like:

```
['b', 'b', 'bb']
```

I have used:

```
re.split(r'^a(.*?)a$', data)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ^ and $ will only match the beginning and end of a line, respectively.
In this case, you will get the desired list by using the line:

```
re.split(r'a(.*?)a', data)[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use re.findall to return the capture group values with the pattern:

```
a([^\sa]+)(?=a)
```

- `a` Match an `a` char
- `([^\sa]+)` Capture group 1, repeat matching any char except `a` (or a whitspace char if you don't want to match spaces)
- `(?=a)` Positive lookahead, assert `a` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RdpY0x/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"a([^\sa]+)(?=a)"
s = "abababba"

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['b', 'b', 'bb']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list comprehension to achieve this:

```
s = "abababba"
l = [x for x in s.split("a") if not x == ""]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'b', 'bb']
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a normal split:

```
"abababba".split("a") --> ['', 'b', 'b', 'bb', '']
```

And remove the empty parts as needed:

```
# remove all empties:

[*filter(None,"abababba".split("a"))] -> ['b', 'b', 'bb']
```

or

```
# only leading/trailing empties (if any)

"abababba".strip("a").split("a") --> ['b', 'b', 'bb']
```

or

```
# only leading/trailing empties (assuming always enclosed in 'a')

"abababba".split("a")[1:-1]  --> ['b', 'b', 'bb']
```

If you must use a regular expression, perhaps findall() will let you use a simpler pattern while covering all edge cases (ignoring all empties):

```
re.findall(r"[^a]+","abababba") --> ['b', 'b', 'bb']
re.findall(r"[^a]+","abababb")  --> ['b', 'b', 'bb']
re.findall(r"[^a]+","bababb")   --> ['b', 'b', 'bb']
re.findall(r"[^a]+","babaabb")  --> ['b', 'b', 'bb']
```